# How to chnage the uploads directory path in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

but it is only chnage the path witin wordpress folder.

I need to setup My uploads folder outsite the my C drive. I have setup the server configuration but unable to set the path in wordpress
my current path uploads directory is

```
C:/xampp/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```

but the path is needed that

```
D:/images/uploads
```

Answer (score -1):

**Change Default Media Folder**

Open your wp-config.php file, locoed at the root of your WordPress installation, and add the following snippet:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/myimages')
```

Make sure you add this code before the line:

```
require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);
```

If the directory doesn’t already exist, WordPress will automatically create it as long as the wp-content folder is writeable. Otherwise you can great the folder yourself via FTP, cPanel etc.

You can also change the way uploads are organized. If you open your uploads folder you’ll notice that files, by default, are sorted into years. You can change your file organization so that all media files are dumped in the one folder. Go to Settings > Media and uncheck “Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders.”

Not only will it make your URLs simpler, it will also make it easier to see all your files in one place instead of having to sort through month and year directories.

Comment: this will chnage only the folder name within the wordpres folder. I need to change the drive of uploads folder

Comment: http://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/media-settings.jpeg